# which way works better? html link to file

Tags: html, css

so have multiple files within folders and everything but i have one includes/header.php

so let's say I have one file in addons/index.php and another in addons/txt/text.php and both include the header.php with include("includes/header.php);

the links get messed up like the header style link that is css/header.css will need change depending on the file because it will work in the addons/index.php but not in the addons/txt/text.php so my solution is to do a direct link https://localhost/filename/css/header.css so then it will work in all page no matter of there location is this a correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a  base URL for your project is the better option. You can set it in your `header.php` and get to edit it one time every time you change the host or site folder

```
<?php $baseurl = "http://localhost/filename";?>
<link href = "<?php echo $baseurl ;?>/css/header.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

you can use the base URL on all the pages that include `header.php` like so

```
<image src="<?php echo $baseurl ;?>/images/logo.png"/>
```